# Calling javascript on onsubmit to post users input

Tags: javascript, forms, function, operator-keyword, onsubmit

I'm having a really difficult time with this onsubmit.  Every time I try to call my function, I get nothing.  As soon as I hit 'submit', my form empties and nothing happens.  It should be calling a new page to display the information that the user has entered.

I have gone through question after question on stackoverflow and can't find my answer.  I'm just learning Javascript and this is probably going to be a very easy question for you all, but since I can't find anything on here that's novice level, I'm stuck referring to you guys for my 'simple' answer.  I'm not sure how to submit this question without a huge block of code... so... I apologize for the lengthy code. I did only use one example from the form.

```
<script>
function ScheduledEvent(evtDate){
    evt.evtDate = evtDate;
    evt.PrintEvent = PrintEvent
}
function PrintEvent(){
    document.write("<p> You have scheduled an event on " + evt.evtDate);
}
function Validate(){
    with (document.evtForm){
        events = new ScheduledEvent(evtDate.value);
    }
    with (events){
        evt.PrintEvent();
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

<form name="evtForm" onsubmit="Validate()">
```

If you need to see more code I'll be happy to oblige.  All of the form names and variables match.  I cannot figure this out and would love your help.

Comment: When you submit a form, it reloads the page with the response from the server.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Your form doesn't have an `action` attribute, so it would probably just reload the same page upon submit (and show a new empty form).

Comment: form needs an 'action' for which you supply a url. (and a method such as post or get.) maybe you should just call your method(s) from a button?

Comment: onsubmit of your form calls validate, with always returns true, so the form with submit to the server, defaulting to the same url as you have no action defined, it will use GET (the default) as you have not method defined  which will cause the page to reload and show a new blank form (unless the server is changing that). Also don't use `with` (as noted [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)).

Answer (score 0):

Well your doing it wrong then. There are a lot of reasons behind this -

1. Your `Validate()` method is returning `true`, which means it will not stop the form submit. So the form will be submitted and the same page will reload. Which explains why it is getting reset. It's happening locally so you are not being able to see the page refresh.
2. You are calling `PrintEvent()` before the form is submitted. Thus `document.write` is actually writing the value in the document but after writing, the page is posted back and reloaded. So you cannot see the updated information.
3. You are using `document.write`, which only write on current page, so it will not take you to a different page. And remember, every time a page loads, so does the javascript, which means your javascript objects and states are lost and it is re-initialised.
4. When javascript writes with `document.write` it will not clear previously rendered items, that includes HTMLs, the form and whatever you have on that page already rendered. It will just append the line at the bottom of the `body` tag. To test, return `false` from `validate` and you will be able to see the item written.
5. If you are willing to use a new page, then you have to save the value to somewhere, either on the server or using client `local storage` or `cookie`. Try googling about how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! The code written is exactly out of my book the way that they want you to do it, so its frustrating to me that I'm typing exactly the way that I'm supposed to and not getting anywhere.  All your answers make sense, but I just didn't know that (ignorance).